# Is there a support for schema versioning in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

To evolve the schema of documents or models schema versioning pattern [1] could be a way to go. Does spring data mongodb support this pattern? We use mainly the interface `MongoRepository<T, ID>` where `T` is our document.

I think of having `MyDocumentV1` and `MyDocumentV2` and could imagine to have an interface `MyDocument`. How to tell the Repository to use either instance based on `schemaVersion`?

[2] https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-schema-versioning/